# Ошибка при компиляции .py в .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyinstaller

Когда я пытаюсь скомпилировать код, у меня выходит вот такая ошибка:

```
110 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
110 INFO: Python: 3.5.2
110 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
112 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Sheih\Desktop\programmer\Svoe\ChangeDataDate\ChangeData
Date.spec
113 INFO: UPX is not available.
115 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Sheih\\Desktop\\programmer\\Svoe\\ChangeDataDate',
 'C:\\Users\\Sheih\\Desktop\\programmer\\Svoe\\ChangeDataDate']
116 INFO: checking Analysis
116 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
116 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
119 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
121 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5075 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5568 INFO: Caching module hooks...
5577 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Sheih\Desktop\programmer\Svoe\ChangeDataDate\Chang
eDataDate.py
5605 INFO: Loading module hooks...
5605 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
5715 WARNING: Cannot read QLibraryInfo output: raised Expecting value: line 1 co
lumn 1 (char 0) when decoding:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'qualname'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python35\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run

    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_
build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'
))
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
241, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line
158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line
500, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410
, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377
, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 736, in impor
tlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 388, in _check_name_wrappe
r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 809, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 668, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 268, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.py", line 23,
 in <module>
    collect_system_data_files(pyqt5_library_info.location['PrefixPath'],
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 67, i
n __getattr__
    qli = json.loads(json_str)
  File "c:\python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Сам код:**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
import time, sys, os


class Folder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(400, 225)
        self.way = 0

        self.calendar = QDateTimeEdit(self)
        self.calendar.setGeometry(10, 10, 380, 35)
        self.calendar.setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy | H:mm:ss")

        btnOpen = QPushButton(self)
        btnOpen.setText("Открыть папку")
        btnOpen.setGeometry(10, 55, 380, 50)
        btnOpen.clicked.connect(self.openFolder)

        self.wayText = QLineEdit(self)
        self.wayText.setGeometry(10, 115, 380, 40)
        self.wayText.setReadOnly(True)

        btnChange = QPushButton(self)
        btnChange.setText("Изменить")
        btnChange.setGeometry(10, 165, 380, 50)
        btnChange.clicked.connect(self.change)

    def change(self):
        if self.way != "":
            year = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("yyyy")
            month = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("MM")
            day = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("dd")
            hour = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("hh")
            minute = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("mm")
            second = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("ss")

            if year.startswith("0"):
                year = year[1:]
            if month.startswith("0"):
                month = month[1:]
            if day.startswith("0"):
                day = day[1:]
            if hour.startswith("0"):
                hour = hour[1:]
            if minute.startswith("0"):
                minute = minute[1:]
            if second.startswith("0"):
                second = second[1:]

    def openFolder(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select directory")
        self.way = fname
        self.wayText.setText(fname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Folder()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ввожу для компиляции:

`pyinstaller --onefile --icon=name.ico --noconsole myscript.py`

Comment: Вам надо показать код и строку,  которой вы пытаетесь скомпилировать код.

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю почему у вас так получается. У меня компилируется нормально, но иконка не появляется. 
Я обычно делаю так: - вставьте строку `self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icono.png"))` 
 и компилируйте `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole myscript.py`

**myscript.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
import time, sys, os


class Folder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icono.png"))                 # <------------------------
        self.setFixedSize(400, 225)
        self.way = 0

        self.calendar = QDateTimeEdit(self)
        self.calendar.setGeometry(10, 10, 380, 35)
        self.calendar.setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy | H:mm:ss")

        btnOpen = QPushButton(self)
        btnOpen.setText("Открыть папку")
        btnOpen.setGeometry(10, 55, 380, 50)
        btnOpen.clicked.connect(self.openFolder)

        self.wayText = QLineEdit(self)
        self.wayText.setGeometry(10, 115, 380, 40)
        self.wayText.setReadOnly(True)

        btnChange = QPushButton(self)
        btnChange.setText("Изменить")
        btnChange.setGeometry(10, 165, 380, 50)
        btnChange.clicked.connect(self.change)

    def change(self):
        if self.way != "":
            year = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("yyyy")
            month = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("MM")
            day = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("dd")
            hour = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("hh")
            minute = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("mm")
            second = self.calendar.dateTime().toString("ss")

            if year.startswith("0"):
                year = year[1:]
            if month.startswith("0"):
                month = month[1:]
            if day.startswith("0"):
                day = day[1:]
            if hour.startswith("0"):
                hour = hour[1:]
            if minute.startswith("0"):
                minute = minute[1:]
            if second.startswith("0"):
                second = second[1:]

    def openFolder(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select directory")
        self.way = fname
        self.wayText.setText(fname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Folder()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**icono.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот результат запуска  `myscript.exe`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё равно не помогает. Вылезает такая же ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему.

Создал виртуальную среду: `py -m venv venv`
Далее запустил среду: `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`
После установил нужные модули: PyQt5, PyQt5-tools, sip, pyinstallerr

Ввёл: `pyinstaller --onefile --icon=icon.ico --noconsole myscript.py`

И файл скомпилировался