# Почему после сборки проекта через pyinstaller не отображается иконка?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyinstaller, qicon

Минимально-воспроизводимый пример для воспроизведения:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello World")
        l = QtWidgets.QLabel("My simple app.")
        l.setMargin(10)
        self.setCentralWidget(l)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
```

Когда я собираю проект с помощью вот этой команды:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --icon=hand.ico app.py
```

Я хочу чтобы менялся ярлык готового **.exe** файла, но этого не происходитimport sys

Вот иконка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя везде где я читал, это должно работать, что я ни так делаю?

Вот что у меня получается когда я ввожу команду:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --icon=hand.ico app.py
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А я хочу чтобы вместо ярлыка дискеты у меня была моя иконка на exe файле

Comment: Там реально формат ico? Или png/jpg?

Comment: Я знаю что использовать можно только ico, когда я собираю я использую ico

Comment: Понятно, но я должен был спросить :) А если указать полный путь до `hand.ico` работает? Мб у вас рабочая папка скрипта не та же папка где находятся иконка и скрипт app.py?

Comment: Иконка и скрипты в одной папке

Comment: Попробуйте перебросить иконку в папку ```\dist\main\```

Comment: Перебросил, когда собираю проект он просто удаляет ее оттуда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отобразить значок в нашем окне, нам нужно добавить вызов `setWindowIcon()`.

**q1393096.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Hello World")
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("My simple app.")
        label.setMargin(10)
        self.setCentralWidget(label)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('hand_icon.ico'))                          # !!! +++
    w = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
```

---

**`pyinstaller --windowed --icon=hand_icon.ico q1393096.py`**

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Вы меня немного не поняли, мне нужно, чтобы значок был не в окне в углу, а ярлыком приложения, которое получится после сборки
>
> Я знаю как меня значок в углу приложения, знаю как менять в панели задач, но я хочу поменять именно ярлык приложения, на который я кликаю два раза и он запускает приложения

Да, теперь я понял что не понимаю вас. Добавить к вышесказанному пока нечего. Вы упомянули об ярлыке и я вам продемонстрирую на изобразениях как это выглядит у меня. Я честно не понимаю где еще вам показать иконку.

1.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update 2**

> А я хочу чтобы вместо ярлыка дискеты у меня была моя иконка на exe файле

У меня именно так как вы хотите и получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы меня немного не поняли, мне нужно, чтобы значок был не в окне в углу, а ярлыком приложения, которое получится после сборки

Comment: @Tesla отвечает ли это на ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128075/pyqt5-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/1128212#1128212 или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999374/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-py-%d0%b2-exe/999487#999487

Comment: Я знаю как меня значок в углу приложения, знаю как менять в панели задач, но я хочу поменять именно ярлык приложения, на который я кликаю два раза и он запускает приложения

Comment: Я подправил свой вопрос, посмотрите на скриншот, когда я собираю проект мне нужно изменить иконку exe но она не меняется вот в чем проблема

Comment: Странно, у меня просто ничего не получается, вот я и не пойму что ни так

Comment: @Tesla попробуйте именно с моим примером `q1393096.py` --> `pyinstaller --windowed --icon=hand_icon.ico q1393096.py` , `hand_icon.ico` - в формате `.ico`, не забудьте положить  `hand_icon.ico` рядом с `q1393096.exe`. Да и какая у вас ОС?

Comment: Я с вашим делал 2 раза, ничего не выходит, у меня window 10? немного не поняла, как положить ```hand_icon.ico``` рядом с exe, после сборки проекта нужно засунуть иконку потом еще туда же в ту папку которая собралась?

Comment: @Tesla ДА, после сборки проекта нужно засунуть `hand_icon.ico` в ту папку где `q1393096.exe`

Comment: Боже, заработало, просто нигде в документациях об этом не говорилось, простите что отнял у вас столько времени, спасибо!

Comment: @Tesla пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Многое перепробовал. помогло создание скрипта myscript.spec - вот тут есть описание https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#using-pyinstaller
А иконку добавил в своей программе используя

```
root.iconbitmap('T:\\папка\\папка\\icon.ico')
```

### myscript.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['mysoft.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='Название программы',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['T:\путь к папке\icon.ico'],
)
```

едите сюда код