# Как привязать значок к приложению PySide6?

Tags: python, pyside

Проверьте код, хочу привязать значок к приложению. В IDE если запустить приложение то значок показывается как в левом верхнем углу, так и в трее. Но стоит скомпилировать приложение в .ехе то значка нет.

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QSize
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Programm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 300)
        icon = QIcon() # Привязка иконки
        icon.addFile(u"icon.ico", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = Programm()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+exe+%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: отвечает ли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1393096/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-pyinstaller-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0 на ваш вопрос?